# how to install a bzr plugin?

Tags: python, bazaar, bazaar-plugins

For a novice, the steps required to can install the bzr plugin push-and-update are not clear.

The plugin is described [here in the bzr documentation](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/plugins/en/push-and-update-plugin.html), and there is another [documentation page that explains how to install plugins](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/plugins/en/plugin-installation.html)

But there is no clear guide to installation.

Comment: Did you remove your previous attempts?

Comment: @AmanicA no - removing the version in my home directory seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- find the plugin directory

  ```
  python
  >>> from bzrlib import plugin
  >>> list_of_bzr_plugin_paths = [os.path.abspath(p)
  ... for p in plugin.get_standard_plugins_path()]
  ```

  The libraries (on ubuntu) are:

  - `$HOME/.bazaar/plugins'`
  - `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bzrlib/plugins'`

<strike>*  Install from launchpad</strike>

```
    bzr branch lp:bzr-push-and-update
```

- Install from launchpad, renaming the directory to avoid errors.

  ```
  bzr branch lp:bzr-push-and-update ~/.bazaar/plugins/push_and_update
  ```

Comment: ``bzr version`` will tell you the location of the Bazaar configuration, the user-specific plugins live in the ``plugins`` directory under there.